# jquery attribute indexOf

Tags: asp.net, jquery

When I am getting at an attribute `onclick` of custom(Reporting Services) checkbox it gives me correct result. However when I am trying to use `indexOf` on that result it says "Object doesn't support this property or method", i.e. this is fine, gives me a long string

```
$('input[id*=CustomCheckBox]').click(function()
{
      alert( $(this).attr("onclick") );


});
```

But this gives an error(object doesn't support this property or method):

```
$('input[id*=CustomCheckBox]').click(function()
{
     if ($(this).attr("onclick").indexOf("SomeString") > -1 )
     {
          //do some processing here

     }
}
```

What would I need to modify so that `indexOf` is working properly?

Comment: You shouldn't use `onclick` as an *attribute*, this will be unreliable...it is one way (and a valid one) to declare an **event** (not an *attribute* in this case), but nothing in the spec says it has to remain accessible on the DOM as an attribute once the event is hooked up.

Comment: The onclick attribute is probably a Function, not a String.  The alert() call is converting it to a String before displaying it.

Comment: @Nick Not really using `onclick` myself but this is a 3rd party checkbox that has `onclick` defined. Question is not really about that attribute but more about why `indexOf` failing

Comment: @jimr wow, that is exactly right `typeof(onclick)` returns a function, but how would I convert that whole function body into string myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Nick Carver above, but if you still need to do it, you simply need to cast the attribute as a string before you try to use `indexOf`. I tested it quickly in Safari and it seemed to work as expected.

```
if (String($(this).attr("onclick")).indexOf("SomeString") > -1 )
 {
      //do some processing here

 }
```

Comment: This won't work as stated above, for example in firefox the attribute will be `undefined` :)

Comment: @patrick - Woops, I was testing against the wrong div ID, in any case this still isn't guaranteed to be present, the event is though.

Comment: Also seems to be working in IE. Actually this solves my issue

Comment: @patrick - This is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/EzsCE/3/ See how the attribute isn't accurate anymore? The event gets the correct *current* function here, the attribute doesn't.  Now in this case jQuery is normalizing it a bit for you (`.attr()` vs DOM `.getAttribute()`), but don't trust that this is always the case, you should, as a practice, never use `.attr("eventName")` to *reliably* get what's in use.

Comment: @Nick This was the only way for me determine if it's a standard or custom checkbox, there were no other differences I could find. I could do it the way you showed but they could've used event other then `onclick`

Comment: @Victor - The other events are available this way as well, `this.onchange`, etc, everything you can add as an attribute you can get via the DOM, for example this does `this.onchange` at the same time: http://jsfiddle.net/EzsCE/4/

Comment: @Nick - I see that. I had just noticed that it seemed to work in FF, and wondered what I was doing wrong to make it work. ;o)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onclick` **event** itself, not the most efficient, but if it's your only option... You'd do it like this:

```
$('input[id*=CustomCheckBox]').click(function() {
  if (this.onclick && this.onclick.toString().indexOf("SomeString") > -1 ) {
    alert('found!')
  } else {
    alert('not found :(');
  }
});
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/kwBqX/)